# How to remove all many to many objects in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model Foo. Which has many to many relation with Moo.

Now Foo has many objects in its many to many field i.e. it has moo1,moo2, moo3 etc etc
How can I remove all of the objects together ?
I know we can remove each individually .

```
foo = FOO()
foo.save()
foo.moo.add(moo1)
foo.moo.remove(moo1)
```

i.e.

```
foo = FOO()
foo.save()
foo.moo.add(moo1)
foo.moo.add(moo2)
foo.moo.reset() # This should remove all objects that have been added
                  # in this field. This does not work but I want
                  # something like this.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think foo.moo.clear() should work

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`clear`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear) method.

> Removes all objects from the related object set:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
b.entry_set.clear()
```

> Note this doesn’t delete the related objects – it just disassociates them.
>
> Just like remove(), clear() is only available on ForeignKeys where
>   null=True.

Answer (score 0):

use the related objects clear method clear `clear()` to dissociate all Foo related objects

```
moo.foo_set.clear()
```

to delete objects use `delete()`queryset method

```
Foo.objects.all().delete()
```

you can delete by one object using `filter()` default manager method

```
Foo.objects.filter(name='moo1').delete()
```